# Where is '$' under the "normal mode" (after esc-pressing mode) in "Vim" text editor?

Tags: vim

I have hard time realizing, as a beginner, why in "Vim" (Windows 10), when I want to delete a word with a <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>$</kbd> and when I simultaneously press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> on non-numeric key above qwerty... why "Vim" does not recognize that as a <kbd>$</kbd>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finnaly understand it... a cursor must be BEFORE a related "tail" to be eliminated.

PS: In fact problem was with "e212 error: can't write to file"... instead of changing proposed "sudo permissions", while I'm on Win 10 instead, I've just reinstalled a fresh Vim.

So, problem were not with "$" (as it was where always have been) but when one is unsure where problem lies, often makes a wrong diagnosis.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly believe that you confusion stems from the fact that `d$` is not actually meant to delete a word.  Moreover, `dw` (which sound pretty much like "delete word") is not meant to delete a word either.

`d` is a command that will perform its action (deletion) on the next movement right after the command.  Note that `$` moves to the end of the line, and `w` moves to the beginning of the next word.  Therefore:

- `d$` deletes from the cursor position until the end of the line.
- `dw` deletes from the cursor position until the beginning of the next word.

For a better example you should try `d3j`.  `3j` moves three lines below, therefore `d3j` deletes the current lines and the next three lines as well.

---

To delete the word under the cursor (no matter where the cursor is in the word) there are several ways.  Some ways to do it:

- `bdw` first move to the beginning of the word then delete 'till the next word.
- `vawd` visually select the word **a** word (including the space after the word) and delete it.
- `viwd` visually select an **i**nner word and delete it (this leaves the spaces around the word in peace).
- `daw` delete **a** word (without going into visual).
- `diw` delete **i**nner word (without visual).

(Try the visual ones first to see how they work, then you can use the non-visual ones.)

---

Also, we have a [vi.SE](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) section of the website.

Comment: Also `daw`, delete a word, and `diw`, delete inner word, without going to visual.

Comment: @Amadan - Good one, I have updated the answer.  I've kept the visuals so OP can see how things work.

Comment: I've said "word" in passing by, of course have thinked about "deleting" the rest of the line... but than instantly answered to myself, when finally found it...

Namely, I didn't managed imidately that a cursor must be set just before first character of the "tail" which must be erased... I've firstly thinked that it is in some connection with punctual dots (.) as "delimiters"... but quickly I've managed that creators of that ultimate editor didn't want to be soo "exclusive" and delicate...

Comment: Anyway, thanx to everybody for response I've bookmarked this page for further "references" in the future... I hope my learning of "Vim" will make me faster and more thorough...